# Return multiple data from Excel sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a slight problem. I created a UserForm with 40 TextBoxes that submits its contents to `sheet1`.

The userform generates a time stamp in a label (`label2`) using `Format(Now(), "H:MM")`.

When I click the `submit` button upon filling the form, each filled TextBox is submitted to column 1 in `sheet1` alongside the time stamp to column 2 in `sheet1`.

See code below:

```
Dim Emptyrow As Long
Emptyrow = Worksheetfunction.CountA(Range(A:A)) + 1

Cell(Emptyrow, 1) = textbox1.Value
Cell(Emptyrow, 2) = label2.Value

Cell(Emptyrow + 1, 1) = textbox2.Value
Cell(Emptyrow + 1, 2) = label2.Value

Cell(Emptyrow + 2, 1) = textbox3.Value
Cell(Emptyrow + 2, 2) = label2.Value

Cell(Emptyrow + 3, 1) = textbox4.Value
Cell(Emptyrow + 3, 2) = label2.Value

Cell(Emptyrow + 4, 1) = textbox5.Value
Cell(Emptyrow + 4, 2) = label2.Value
.
.
.
.
Cell(Empty row + 39, 1) = textbox40.Value
Cell(Empty row + 39, 2) = label2.Value
```

All filled textboxes submitted at an instance will have the same time stamp in column 2.

I want a situation where I can *recall all contents* submitted to `sheet1` back to the TextBoxes using the time stamp as my filter.

I would like to achieve this by placing a recall TextBox at the top of the UserForm and then filling the desired time stamp as my search criteria to recall contents from column 1 in `sheet1`.

I know this is possible, but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Instead of a textbox, Use a combobox. Create a unique list of time stamp using a collection or dictionary from that column in the worksheet and populate the combobox from that collection/dictionary :)

Comment: Also a better way to write data to the cell would be to store data in an array and then write that array to the worksheet. It will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth Rout, how do I write the codes

Comment: Start by googling **1.** How to create a Collection/Dictionary **2.** How to Write to Array **3.** Write array to worksheet :)

Comment: I'll do that right away. Thanks